# Javascript - unable to call function from another file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to call a function from one file in another js file.

general.js

```
function delete_post(post_id, post_type, nonce) {
    $.post(Ajax.ajaxurl, { action: 'delete_post', post_id: post_id, nonce: nonce, post_type: post_type}, function (data) {
        var result = $.parseJSON(data);
        if (result.status == 'error') {
            $('#post_'+post_id).prepend('<div class="alert alert-danger">' + result.message + '</div>');
        }
        if (result.status == 'success') {
            $('#post_'+post_id).fadeOut(1000, function(){

                $(this).remove();
            });
        }
    });
}
```

details.js

```
$('body').on('click', '.remove-row', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var post_id = $(this).attr('data-target');
    var nonce = $(this).attr('data-nonce');
    var parent_id = $(this).attr('data-parent');
    var post_type = $(this).attr('data-post_type');
    bootbox.confirm(Ajax.are_you_sure, function(result) {
        if (result) {

            delete_post(post_id, post_type, nonce);

        }
    });
});
```

On the page they are loaded in the correct order:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://domain.com/js/general.js?ver=3.9.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://domain.com/js/details.js?ver=3.9.1'></script>
```

However, when I click on the `remove-row` button, I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: delete_post is not defined`.

What am I missing?

Comment: This doesn't make sense. in your details.js put : `alert(typeof delete_post)` --- does it alert?

Comment: `alert(typeof delete_post)` shows `string`

Comment: `delete_post` not `'delete_post'`. are u sure ?

Comment: sorry, that returns `undefined`.

Comment: are you sure the `<script` tag is excat paste ? no defer/async attributes ?

Comment: ok printscreen the exact look of `<script` usages and upload it

Comment: I copied that directly from ther HTML...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error tells us that you haven't shown all of `general.js`, and in particular that your function declaration for `delete_post` is inside another function (one possible example below). So it's not a global.

If you want to make it a global, you can do that by putting this line in `general.js`:

```
window.delete_post = delete_post;
```

The properties of the `window` object are globals.

In general, I would recommend keeping globals to a minimum, so you might want to have a single global object you use for all your stuff, along these lines:

```
if (!window.myApp) {
    window.myApp = {};
}
window.myApp.delete_post = delete_post;
```

...and then instead of

```
delete_post(post_id, post_type, nonce);
```

...in your other file, use

```
myApp.delete_post(post_id, post_type, nonce);
```

---

When I say it's inside another function, here's one example of that:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function delete_post() {
        // ...
    }

});
```

Your example may look slightly different, but that's the gist.

Comment: Thanks, that was it. I had the definition of the function in `jQuery(document).ready(function($){})`...